# Subfloat labels don't display properly

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats

The screenshot has the bottom part of a figure with two subfigures. As you can see, the labels have a very narrow width. I don't understand why.

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \subfloat[Frequency Histogram]{}\includegraphics[width=2.75in,height=2.5in]{left-figure}
  \subfloat[Boxplots]{}\includegraphics[width=2.75in]{right-figure}
  \caption{The caption of the entire figure which displays fine but not shown here} 
  \label{whatever}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is the same layout as in [this wikibook page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/File:Latex_example_subfig.png) (where the subfigure text fits on a line under each image).

Thanks ahead for the advice.

Comment: what if one of your figures is very thin and the subcaption therefore wraps every few letters - do you know a way around this? I tried using `\mbox{subcaption}` but then the subcaption doesn't line up with the index. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The layout is correct for the code you are using! i.e.

1. centering
2. Empty subfloat with a "subcaption"
3. graphic
4. Empty subfloat with a "subcaption"
5. graphic
6. caption

Anything that you want to appear as a subfloat needs to be enclosed in the

```
\subfloat[Optional TOC caption][Sub-caption]{subfloat body}
```

So for your example try ths:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \subfloat[Frequency Histogram]{\includegraphics[width=2.75in,height=2.5in]{left-figure}}
  \subfloat[Boxplots]{\includegraphics[width=2.75in]{right-figure}}
  \caption{The caption of the entire figure which displays fine but not shown here} 
  \label{whatever}
\end{figure}
```

This results in:

1. centering
2. Subfloat with a "subcaption"

   1. contents graphic
3. Subfloat with a "subcaption"

   1. contents graphic
4. caption

NB!

```
\subfloat { body } % correct
\subfloat {} body  % wrong
```

For more info & more examples see:

```
$texdoc subfig
```

Comment: Horay =) hit 1000 mark with this answer ;-)